# Remove decimal values

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal

I want to remove decimal values only if all the decimal values are `0`.

If I use `parseFloat()`:

> 50.00  => 50
>   60.50 => 60.5

My expected output:

> 50.00  => 50
>   60.50 => 60.50

I can't use `Math.round()`, `Math.trunk()`, `Math.floor()`, `ParseInt()`.

Is there any other way?

Comment: do you have a string and want a string back?

Comment: JavaScript does not support trailing zeros. So if you want them, you got to work with strings.

Comment: It is ugly/tricky, but it can work too: can't you just use the number as a string and just call `parseFloat()` if it matches a regexp like that `\.0*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `toFixed()` and RegEx `/[.,]00$/` with `replace()` like the following:

```js
var num1 = (50.00).toFixed(2).replace(/[.,]00$/, "");
var num2 = (60.50).toFixed(2).replace(/[.,]00$/, "");
console.log(num1)
console.log(num2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
const formatTo = n => Number.isInteger(n) ? n : parseFloat(n).toFixed(2);

console.log(formatTo(50.00))
console.log(formatTo(60.50))
```

Comment: By far the most elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

With given string, you could remove all zeroes after the decimal point.

```js
var values = ['50.00', '60.50'];

console.log(values.map(s => s.replace(/\.0*$/, '')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since JavaScript does not support trailing zeros, I assume you are working with numbers and will have to convert them to strings. So in the case you would need to use toFixed() and remove the double zeros

```js
function trimZeros (num) {
  return num.toFixed(2).replace(/\.00/,"")
}

console.log(50, trimZeros(50))
console.log(60.5, trimZeros(60.5))
console.log(0.5, trimZeros(0.5))
console.log(100.01, trimZeros(100.01))
```

if it is just a string you have, than you can just do a reg exp on it

```
function trimZeros (numStr) {
  return numStr.replace(/\.00/,"")
}
```